# strtok twice a char*

Tags: c, string, strtok

I have a file where I get line by line a char* like :

0   1_12    5_15    6_20

where every group of digits is separated by a tabulation. I have used strtok function to get every group of tokens as:

- 0
- 1_12
- 5_15
- 6_20

But now, I cannot use strtok again to separate the digits on 1_12 , 5_15 etc...
I don't want to just use separators="\t\n_" because I need to get these values to put them into variables, as if the first digit of 1_12 represent an hour and 12 a number of seconds.

Any Idea of how can I re-use again strtok?

I have also seen the function strtok_r function but seems to not help me more ...

Comment: Why can't you use `strtok` on each token?

Comment: *Any Idea of how can I re-use again strtok* -- Call `strtok` again, but with the correct arguments?  It's not as if  the `strtok` function disappears, never to be used again.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie maybe they mean they are calling strtok in a loop on the original string, but they want to process the first substring before going onto the next strtok call for the original string

Comment: If that's the case, `strok_r()` is useful.

Comment: although if the cases all only have a single underscore then it'd be pretty straightforward to process it without a strtok variant

Comment: You can't use `strtok()` on two sequences concurrently.  You _can_ use `strtok_r()` on POSX systems or `strtok_s()` on Windows systems; if used correctly, it allows what you need.  Using `strtok()` in a function `A` means that (a) any function that is called while `A` is using it cannot itself use `strtok()`, and (b) if a function is using `strtok()`, it cannot call your function `A` to do any processing.